# how to generate hfiles then bulk load into hbase with spark?

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-spark, hbase, bulk-load

everyone,I have tried varieties of methods to achieve hbase bulkload with spark. such as [opencore](http://www.opencore.com/blog/2016/10/efficient-bulk-load-of-hbase-using-spark/),[scala load](http://www.openkb.info/2015/01/how-to-use-scala-on-spark-to-load-data.html),however,they can work on local master with spark,not yarn.my codes follow.

```
Dataset<Row> sqlDF = spark.sql(sql);
JavaRDD<Row> rowJavaRDD = sqlDF.javaRDD();

JavaPairRDD<ImmutableBytesWritable, TreeSet<KeyValue>> pairRDD = rowJavaRDD.mapToPair(
            row->convertToKVs(row,fieldArray)//in method :TreeSet<KeyValue> kvSet = new TreeSet<>(KeyValue.COMPARATOR);
    );

pairRDD.repartitionAndSortWithinPartitions(new HashPartitioner(1));

JavaPairRDD<ImmutableBytesWritable, KeyValue> cellRDD = pairRDD.flatMapToPair(row ->{
        List<Tuple2<ImmutableBytesWritable, KeyValue>> kvs = new ArrayList<>();
        TreeSet<KeyValue> kvSet = row._2;
        for (KeyValue keyValue : kvSet) {
            kvs.add(new Tuple2<>(row._1,keyValue));
        }
        return kvs.iterator();
    });

... job conf ...

HFileOutputFormat2.configureIncrementalLoad(job, table);
cellRDD.saveAsNewAPIHadoopFile(hFilePath,ImmutableBytesWritable.class,KeyValue.class,HFileOutputFormat2.class,job.getConfiguration());
```

when I use `spark-submit --master yarn` to execute the codes ,the exception 
`Added a key not lexically larger than previous. key=...` is raised,I know the exception is caused by the table columns hasn't been sorted lexically ,  but why the exception is raised even though I have used `new TreeSet<>(KeyValue.COMPARATOR)` to sort the columns.

will someone tell me how to fix it? thanks in advance.

**edit**: the cause is the pairRdd has same rowkey result. and through distcp,I achieve bulkload spread across different hbase clusters.

Comment: look at  https://github.com/zaratsian/SparkHBaseExample

Comment: @shay__ I have found the cause is that the sql query two complete same rowkey result. thanks your reply very much .